# How Can I Give Route To Swiper Captions in Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, swiper.js

I wanted to give route to cations in swiper slider in Laravel. But I didn't manage it. Is it possible to give route to captions? Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

```html
<div class="carousel-inner am-slider" data-slider="true" data-slider-position="horizontal" data-slider-autoplay="false" data-slider-timeout="1000" data-slider-lazy="true" data-slider-start="0" data-slider-current-page="0">
          @foreach ($cat_am as $key => $item)
                        <a href="{{ route("{$item['type']}.detail", ['title' => Str::slug($item['title'], '-'), 'id' => $item['id']]) }}">
                            <div class="amSlider filigran"> 
                                    <figcaption class="category-fig">
                                        <span class="title text-white">{!! Str::limit($item['slider_title'] == '' ? $item['title'] : $item['slider_title'] , 100 , '...') !!}</span>
                                    </figcaption>
                                    
                                    <img onerror="imgError(this)" 
                                        src="{{ config("base-url.base_{$item['type']}_img_path") }}745x385-{{ $item['cover_image'] }}"
                                        data-errorsrc="{{ config("base-url.base_{$item['type']}_img_path") }}743x385-{{ $item['cover_image'] }}"
                                        alt="{{ $item['title'] }}" title="{{ $item['title'] }}" width="743" height="385">    
                            </div>
                        </a>
           @endforeach
           <ul class="pagination" id="amList"></ul>
</div>
```